# Linked List JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to write some JavaScript in JsFiddle where a doubly linked list is created, then a node can be added to the end. I have done so, but want to fill the list differently.

Here is what I have so far

HTML

```
Create A New List, Then Add A Node!
<br/>
<br/>
<input type="textbox" id="Values" />
<input type="button" value="Create New List" onClick="createList()" />
<input type="button" value="Add a Node" onClick="addNode()" />

<div id="output">

</div>
```

JavaScript

```
var newList = new DoublyLinked();


function DoublyLinked() {
  this.head = null;
  this.tail = null;
  this.length = 0;
}

function NewNode() {
  this.values = null;
  this.next = null;
  this.prev = null;
  return this;
}

DoublyLinked.prototype.add = function(values) {
  var node = new NewNode();
  node.values = values;

  if (this.head === null) {
    this.head = node;
    this.length = 1;
    return node;
  }

  if (this.tail === null) {
    this.tail = node;
    this.tail.prev = this.head;
    this.head.next = this.tail;
    this.length = 2;
    return node;
  }

  this.tail.next = node;
  node.prev = this.tail;
  this.tail = node;
  this.length++;
  return node;
}


function addNode() {
  var values = document.getElementById("values").value;
  newList.add(values);
  newList.print();
}

DoublyLinked.prototype.print = function() {
  if (this.head === null) return "Empty List";
  var display = " ";
  var counter = 0;
  var node = this.head;
  while (node !== null) {
    counter = counter + 1;
    display += "Node: " + counter + " Content: " + node.values + "</br>";
    node = node.next;
  }
  document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = display;
}

function createList(values) {
  for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    values = String.fromCharCode(65 + i);
    newList.add(values);
    newList.print();
  }
}
```

The code above should insert nicely into fiddle if testing, however JS needs to have set no wrap in body load type

Instead of populating the list at the end with a loop in function createList,  I would like to populate it with something like shown below, having trouble writing the code to populate the list differently

```
    function createList(values) {

  newList.add("A")
  newList.add("B")
  newList.add("C")
  newList.add("D")
  newList.add("E")
  newList.print();
```

With this how it is ( the piece of code above in place of the loop) I  can generate the list but not add a node

Comment: So...what's your issue? There's no mention of what problem you're facing

Comment: Having Trouble writing the code to populate the list differently

Comment: Yes I understand that you are having trouble. What sort of trouble? What's the error? What do you expect that you're not seeing?

Comment: 1. Post the code
2. Why does it need to be before
3. This doesn't make sense, how are you going to make a DoublyLinked list before DoublyLinked lists exist?

Comment: @Jay I still have no idea what you're asking. What do you mean by "generate the list"?

Comment: Adding the contents to the list A,B,C,D,E, and retaining functionality. The list is being created initially with a loop, I want to eliminate that.

Comment: @Jay So....remove the loop and insert your code instead. Did you try that?

Comment: Yes I found the error, thank you for your help, it is very appreciated

Comment: @Jay I'm glad you found your answer - but if you want to get help on StackOverflow in the future, you really need to get better at asking and explaining your questions

Comment: My apologies, I'm still quite a novice, so finding the problem, phrasing, etc. is still pretty terrible I know. I will try to improve on what you have suggested. Thank you again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the id Values in HTML, the id being called is values, no capitals. Values was not being instantiated, fixed the typo. Runs great.